# Java Array that creates sequential links with <a href>

Tags: java

Code that creates files with the file name as array contents, the file has word with links previous for the word before and next for the word after, at present it creates files but

[image: the code prints]

!does iterate the array just prints array content as the position specified by array, it should iterate array write array content as word a previous link with previous array content and next link with next array content

```
public class WrHtmlWithLincs 
   {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
    { 
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;         

    try
    {   
        String word[];
        word = new String[14];
        word[0] = "Software";
        word[1] = "Java";
        word[2] = "Android";
        word[3] = "Code";
        word[4] = "Computer Science";
        word[5] = "Satellite Navigation";
        word[6] = "Communications";
        word[8] = "Calculator";
        word[9] = "JavaScript";
        word[10] = "Stanford";
        word[11] = "Mathematics";            

        for(String Ad : word)
        {            
        try
        {
        fw = new FileWriter("F:\\" + Ad + ".html");            
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("<Table align='center' border='4' color = 'cyan'>");    

        bw.write("<TR>"); 

        bw.write("<TD>"); 
        bw.write("<a href=" + word[y] + ".html>");                                 
        bw.write("Previous"); 
        bw.write("</a>");  
        bw.write("</TD>"); 

        bw.write("<TD>"); 
        bw.write(word[y]); 
        bw.write("</TD>");          

        bw.write("<TD>"); 
        bw.write("<a href=" + word[y] + ".html>");                                 
        bw.write("Next"); 
        bw.write("</a>");
        bw.write("</TD>");             

        bw.write("</TR>");            
        bw.write("<Table>");                        
        }
        catch(IOException d)
        {
        d.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
        try {
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();

            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException d) {
            d.printStackTrace();
        }

        }          

        }   
    }                    
    catch(Exception d)
    {
        d.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();

            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException d) {
            d.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're creating 12 files, one for each word, but all 12 files are hardcoded with `word[0]`, `word[1]`, and `word[2]`. Don't you want the file content to change too? --- Try changing `for(String Ad : word)` to `for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++)` so you can use `word[i - 1]`, `word[i]`, and `word[i + 1]` in the generation of the content.

Comment: *FYI:* You should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to close your writer. Do they really still teach that *old* finally-ifnull-close logic? Try-with-resource was added in Java 7, way back in 2011 (ancient history).

Comment: *Hint:* Ask yourself what the `Previous` link should do in the first file, and what the `Next` link should do in the last file.

Comment: cause the version is previous try with resources doesn't worcs on my machine is it java development eight and after

Comment: What does *"cause the version is previous"* mean? Are you running Java 6 or earlier? If so, why on earth are you learning Java on such an old version? Current version is Java 10. If running Java 7 or later, try-with-resources will work.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerEsception  with for(int y= 0; y < word.length; y++)

Comment: How can `word` be null when you defined it right before the loop?

Comment: Java: 1.8.0_141; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 25.141-b15  thats java eight should try with resources is it more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that will work for you. It's the closest thing to an easy magic solution I can think of.

Paste this code somewhere in the class you are working in:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TriConsumer {

    abstract void consume(Object before, Object current, Object after);

}

public static final forContext(Object[] arr, TriConsumer consumer){
    if (arr == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        consumer.consume(i == 0 ? null : arr[i - 1], arr[i], i == arr.length - 1 ? null : arr[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

And you can use this loop by doing something like this:

```
Word[] wordsArray = //Something

forContext(wordsArray, (previous, current, next) -> {

    //Do what you want with the function.
    System.out.println("The previous word: " + previous);
    System.out.println("The current word: " + current);
    System.out.println("The next word: " + next);

});
```

Edit: I think this requires java 8 or higher?